# purescript type signature fails to compile, code works fine without; suggested signature not working

Tags: purescript

The following code produces this error:

```
module Broken1 where

import Control.Monad.Aff.Class (MonadAff)
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff())
import DOM.HTML.Types
import Halogen
import DOM
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception
import Control.Monad.Aff.AVar
import Prelude

import qualified Halogen.HTML.Indexed as H

data State = State
data Query a = Query a

ui :: forall eff g. (MonadAff (HalogenEffects eff) g) => Component State Query g
ui = component (\_ -> H.div_ []) (\(Query next) -> pure next)

main' :: forall eff a. (HTMLElement -> Aff (HalogenEffects eff) a) 
                 -> Aff (HalogenEffects eff) Unit
main' addToDOM = do
    { node: node, driver: driver } <- runUI ui State

    let driver' :: Natural Query (Aff (HalogenEffects eff))
        driver' = driver

    return unit
```

the error:

```
  at Broken1.purs line 34, column 19 - line 36, column 5

    Could not match type
      a2
    with type
      a1

  while trying to match type a2
    with type a1
  while checking that expression driver
    has type Query a1 -> Aff ( avar :: AVAR
                             , err :: EXCEPTION
                             , dom :: DOM
                             | eff1
                             )
                         a1
  in value declaration main'
```

If I omit the type signature for `driver'`, there is no compiler error, as I was hoping.  If I ask `psc` for a signature (by replacing the type with `_`), this is the suggestion:

```
Wildcard type definition has the inferred type

forall a. Query a -> Aff ( dom :: DOM
                         , err :: EXCEPTION
                         , avar :: AVAR
                         | eff4
                         )
                     a
```

When I cut&paste this into the code instead of my original type, the error is the same as above.

In the second case this actually makes sense, since the quantifier opens a new scope for a which should be captured in the signature of main'.  But even if I remove the `forall a`, the type error sticks around.

garyb earlier today on #purescript said it may be a bug in the type checker.  I am posting this here anyway until that is established fact.

thanks! (:

Comment: see also: https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/1793